# Wolfram|Alpha query doesn't compute answer

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I typed

```
== integral (e^cosx)((cosx)^2)(sinx) from x=0 to pi
```

into Mathematica, but it doesn't seem to generate an answer. What did I do wrong?

I entered the query directly on the Wolfram|Alpha and there it did give an answer.

Comment: Syntax is wrong. Check help pages about 'Integrate' and functions.

Comment: this is in the form for the wolfram alpha querie, so what is wrong with the syntax?
a.e. 
==integral (e^cosx)((cosx)^2) from x=0 to pi will give an answer
but ==integral (e^cosx)((cosx)^2)(sinx)  from x=0 to pi   will not

Comment: It works on WolframAlpha's web interface, but I agree that it doesn't work when I tried it in a notebook by invoking the Alpha interface with `==`. Otherwise, in Mathematica use `NIntegrate[E^Cos[x] Cos[x]^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]` which is honestly not that much more complex. You can also use `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` to receive a symbolic answer.

Comment: The reason why I want to use the alpha interface is for the 'step-by-step' function, if I only want an answer I could type =integral (e^cosx)((cosx)^2)(sinx) from x=0 to pi as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this works (in ver. 12.1) and gives the "Step-By-Step Solution" option:
`WolframAlpha["--Integrate[E^Cos[x]*Cos[x]^2*Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]"]`
but
`WolframAlpha["Integrate[E^Cos[x]*Cos[x]^2*Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]"]`
does not.

Comment: This also works: WolframAlpha["1*Integrate[E^Cos[x]*Cos[x]^2*Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]"]

Comment: yes it works for in version 12.0 as well!

Comment: I tried == 1*integral (e^cosx) ((cosx)^2) (sinx) from x = 0 to pi, and it works now, awesome!

Comment: That's great! I'm still amazed it is ok not having a space between the trig functions and the x.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the indefinite integral

```
sol = WolframAlpha[
  "integral (E^(cos x))((cos x)^2)(sin x) dx", {{"IndefiniteIntegral", 2}, 
   "Content"}, PodStates -> {"IndefiniteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

From the [`first fundamental theorem of calculus`](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html)

```
Subtract @@ ((-(1/2))*E^Cos[x]*
      (-(4*Cos[x]) + Cos[2*x] + 5) /. {{x -> Pi}, {x -> 0}})

(* -(5/E) + E *)
```

Verifying,

```
Integrate[E^Cos[x] Cos[x]^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]

(* -(5/E) + E *)
```